# JComboBox.remove is not working

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am trying to remove selected items in the JComboBox (I have added design time) But remove function is not executed. What am I doing wrong

```
// jComboBox1.removeAllItems(); working
// jComboBox1.removeItem(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()); working
jComboBox1.remove(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()); not working
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such method `remove` in `Class JComboBox`.

You want to use [public void removeItemAt(int anIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#removeItemAt%28int%29):

> Removes the item at anIndex This method works only if the JComboBox
>   uses a mutable data model.

```
jComboBox1.removeItemAt(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex());
```

Comment: There is an inherited `remove(int index)` from java.awt.container though which is why his compiler was OK with it.

Answer (score 1):

From JavaDoc

```
public void remove(int index)

    Removes the component, specified by index, from this container. This method also notifies the layout manager to remove the component from this container's layout via the removeLayoutComponent method.

    Parameters:
        index - the index of the component to be removed
```

But as mentioned in above answers you need to do

```
jComboBox1.removeItemAt(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex());
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want `jComboBox1.removeItemAt(...)`

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#removeItemAt(int)

Comment: Hi everybody thanks for all but at the video i have just watched.. the code was just like this Its very funny.